# PEAR Mailer not found? - Failed opening required 'Mail.php'

Tags: pear, php, fatal-error, include-path

Ok I have no idea why it can't include this file; I have followed the instructions on this page: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

The PEAR install path is: `/usr/local/lib/php`

My include path is:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php"
```

PEAR Mail has been installed from what I can tell - there is a `Mail.php` in the PEAR install path as well as a `mail` directory.

I have restarted services after adding the include path; the full error is:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/username/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 3290
```

I am using it on my other server fine, not sure why it's not working here!?

Answer (score 0):

So you can confirm that the file `/usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php` exists? If that's the case, you may have permission problems so that the file is not readable by your web server.

Check the permissions with `ls -l`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/php|grep Mail
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Sep  5  2011 Mail
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   9903 Sep 26  2010 Mail.php
```

There should be three "r" for `Mail.php`. If that's not the case, fix it with

```
$ chmod og+r /usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php
```

Comment: I just checked & it looks exactly like yours above. Could this possibly be a case of the PHP handler we're using? We're using suPHP but on the other server we're PEAR is running fine I believe it's DSO.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by using the `suPHP` handler; apparently that doesn't work too well with PEAR Mailer.